# Qual seria a possível solução para esse problema com o FacebookAppID?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

[image: Erro FacebookAppID]

Qual poderia ser a solução desse problema, visto que o app id está em string.

Comment: Você adicionou todos as chamadas no `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Verifica se o path do **info.plist** está setado corretamente nas propriedades do projeto, acontece de se perder quando move ele de pasta. Outra tentativa é setar o ID no AppDelegate.

Comment: Como faço para estar o ID no AppDelegate? @LuisHenrique, quais seriam todas? Jeferson Assis

Comment: Vê no final do erro ali no console, estou no celular e a rede está ruim para abrir a imagem. Só no lugar de espaço coloca ponto (espaço era chamada de método em obj-c)

Comment: @LuisHenrique cara marquei ja o ID no appelegate e agora o erro que é (reason: 'fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0') porem ja botei tb a lsapplication com fbauth2 e continua dando isso

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você está usando um AppID inválido ou que já foi cancelado.

Você precisa ir até o [portal de desenvolvedores do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/), verificar se o respectivo app que você criou dentro do portal, para seu app de iOS, tem o mesmo AppID ou não que você está usando.

No pior caso, basta criar um novo app no portal.